# What is the relation between char ~ char32_t type and UTF-8 ~ UTF-32?

Tags: unicode, char, wchar-t, char16-t, char32-t

- char: 8-bit character type
- char16_t: 16-bit character type
- char32_t: 32-bit character type
- wchar_t: 16 ~ 32-bit character type depending on the compiler
- UTF-8: An encoding method that can represent Unicode characters while preserving 8-bit characters
- UTF-16: How to encode Unicode characters using one or two 16-bit values
- UTF-32: How to encode all Unicode characters to 32 bits

It is like above, but it does not understand well.
Did it simply implement UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 as char, char16_t, char32_t types?

Comment: You should learn about UTF-8, the other encoding methods are losing favour these days.

Comment: Your should read this: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/.  Clearly, the answer to your question is No.  (Hint: you need to understand the distinction between types and encodings.)

Comment: Read about  [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), and [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32)